# RenderComponentPresentation() Function is not resolving when used in a Dynamic REL CT

Tags: web8.5, rel

I have one Dynamic CT of type REL, which uses a dream weaver TBB. 
The TBB uses RenderComponentPresentation() to render the linked components of the parent component.

[image]

`@@RenderComponentPresentation(Field, articlepress)@@`

When I publish the main component and try to render it in the page , the parent component renders properly , but the linked components are not resolved and the view-source of the page contains the below tags.

```
  <tridion:ComponentPresentation runat="server" PageURI="tcm:97-45594-16" ComponentURI="tcm:97-45591" TemplateURI="tcm:97-45519-32"/>
  <tridion:ComponentPresentation runat="server" PageURI="tcm:97-45594-16" ComponentURI="tcm:97-45593" TemplateURI="tcm:97-45519-32"/>
```

It works fine when I change the Type of the Component Template to ascx or html fragment.

Am I missing any configuration change?

`I am migrating the building blocks to Tridion 2011(where it works perfectly fine) to SDL Web 8.5.` **So any solution with out changing the CT type will be helpful.**

**Update 1**

In the preview the Linked components are rendering properly in side the TCDL tag. Below is the SDL Preview section

```
<tcdl:ComponentPresentation type="Embedded" componentURI="tcm:97-45594" templateURI="tcm:97-45521-32" xmlns:tcdl="http://www.tridion.com/ContentDelivery/5.3/TCDL">
           ////
         The linked contents are properly rendered here
           ////
</tcdl:ComponentPresentation>
```

Comment: It looks like the TCDL is getting transformed on deployment. What do you see in the source when previewing? Does it properly output the TCDL tags (as opposed to tridion:ComponentPresentation tags with runat=server which are clearly .NET tags)?

Comment: I have just updated the question . The Tcdl tag contains the  parent component and CT information , with the linked component contents rendered properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get this work, we would also need to specify the target language in the tcdl-conf.xml file in the deployer.
[Enabling publishing of Pages with REL format Dynamic Component Presentations](https://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Web-v5/GUID-3ED3EF09-4EE6-48B2-A618-D16634BB9DB8)

**Update:**

I looked at the documentation again and I see the property name to set the target language is different from what you have specified below. Please give a try at it

```
Ability to publish Dynamic Component Presentations in REL format on Web pages in JSP or ASP.NET format

    You can set a new property in tcdl-conf.xml called tcdl.page.target.language, 
which allows you to have SDL Web transform Pages into JSP or ASP.NET for your JSP or ASP.NET Web site, 
while leaving REL Dynamic Component Presentations on the Page unchanged.
```

Comment: Hi Rajesh, im Manas partner so I can give you more information as well .. here is our dcdl-conf.xml ..

    <Properties>
       
        <!--
        <Property Name="tcdl.dotnet.style" Value="controls"/>
        <Property Name="tcdl.jsp.style" Value="tags"/>
        -->
  <Property Name="tcdl.target.language" Value="dotnet"/>

    </Properties>
    <!-- Optional configuration needed in case of using the UGC TCDL transformers -->
    <!--
        <TagBundle Resource="ugc_tag_bundle.xml"/>
    -->
</TCDLEngine>

Comment: sorry, is a mess .. here is clearer :    <Property Name="tcdl.target.language" Value="dotnet"/>

Comment: I have updated my answer now,  we might need to update the tcdl-conf.xml to look like <Property Name="tcdl.target.language" Value="rel"/> and <Property Name="tcdl.page.target.language" Value="dotnet"/>. Please change the settings and restart the deployer and give a try by republishing the items once

Comment: @Rajesh : We only added the <Property Name="tcdl.page.target.language" Value="dotnet"/> and it worked. With having both the property it did not work.